# Change the UITableView's height for HeaderInSection?

Tags: ios, objective-c

My `UITableView`'s style is plain, and I want to change the height of HeaderInSection, but it's remains the default height 22.0.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView.tag == tableOrdersTag)
    {
        return 35;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView.tag == tableOrdersTag)
    {
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frameWidth, 35)];

        view.backgroundColor = COMMON_BACKGROUND_COLOR;

        DDLogVerbose(@"=========tableView  %f", tableView.sectionHeaderHeight);

        return view;
    }
    else
    {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you set the self.tableView.delegate = self; ?

Comment: The way you are doing this is correct. Put break points to those methods & check what part of the code is executing.

Comment: @stevechen yes,i did

Comment: @BC_Dilum those methods are executed right, i have checked that.

Comment: are there multiple sections in table view and do you want to change height for all sections? Also, make sure that the tag you have assigned to the table view is proper.

Comment: Hello,guys,finally,i found out it works, and i didn't set the footer view of section to zero.Sorry....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The place of your NSLog

```
        DDLogVerbose(@"=========tableView  %f", tableView.sectionHeaderHeight);
```

may cause the problem.It should's before the return method:

```
        return view;
```

change the number 35 to 100, you'll find the it works fine.

because the method of

```
tableView:viewForHeaderInSection
```

is behind of

```
tableView:heightForHeaderInSection.
```

When I create a TaleViewController without xib or storyboard  like :

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"heightForHeaderInSection");
        return 100;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 100)];

        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        NSLog(@"=========tableView  %f", tableView.sectionHeaderHeight);
        return view;
}
```

it will print like :

```
 2015-05-21 18:25:30.525 UITableViewHeaderDemo[24727:2350493] heightForHeaderInSection
 2015-05-21 18:25:30.526 UITableViewHeaderDemo[24727:2350493] heightForHeaderInSection
 2015-05-21 18:25:30.526 UITableViewHeaderDemo[24727:2350493] heightForHeaderInSection
 2015-05-21 18:25:30.526 UITableViewHeaderDemo[24727:2350493] heightForHeaderInSection
 2015-05-21 18:25:30.535 UITableViewHeaderDemo[24727:2350493] heightForHeaderInSection
 2015-05-21 18:25:30.535 UITableViewHeaderDemo[24727:2350493] heightForHeaderInSection
 2015-05-21 18:25:30.549 UITableViewHeaderDemo[24727:2350493] heightForHeaderInSection
 2015-05-21 18:25:30.549 UITableViewHeaderDemo[24727:2350493] heightForHeaderInSection
 2015-05-21 18:25:30.550 UITableViewHeaderDemo[24727:2350493] =========tableView  -1.000000
```

but the [image: It works fine]

Comment: The head of section can change now(i set 55),but i put this:                                              - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:      (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView.tag == tableOrdersTag) { 
         NSLog(@"tableview的section height:============:%f",tableView.sectionHeaderHeight);  }}   The result  is still 22.000000

Answer (score 1):

Do this things:-

1. Open interface builder and select table view.
2. Now, Open the size inspector.
3. Find options to set section height.
4. In that, you'll find Header and Footer. Set value of 35 to header.

Try out this. Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all change section height from Xib then

Return following line instead of nil in else then check

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frameWidth, 0)];
```